# page not found error ,even though I have that page in url code

Tags: python, django

This is the error I am getting:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
Using the URLconf defined in portfolio.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
^(?P<path>.*)$
The empty path matched the last one.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

THIS IS MY URL/ SETTINGS file code:

settings:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'jobs.apps.JobsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'portfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'portfoliodb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '#Dhiraj40',
        'HOST' : 'localhost',
        'PORT' : '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
```

URL :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is the complete file on my GitHub:

https://github.com/DhirajChauhan40/portfolio

Please help me solve this error , everything was working and suddenly it stopped and I am stuck on this for 2 weeks now :(

Comment: I don't see any pattern that would match an empty path in your url patterns (Something like `path('', some_view, ...),`). Also I don't see any `MEDIA_URL` or `MEDIA_ROOT` variable in your settings (you have used them as `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`)...

Comment: Looking at your GitHub you have set the setting as `MEDIA_URl` instead of `MEDIA_URL` (notice the difference of small `l` and capital `L`)